Laravel AJAX/JSON Redirecting Issue
newbie here...
I'm trying to populate a form and table using json and ajax. The populating of the data seems working but I am being redirected to a black page with the data that I am trying to get.
Redirected Page
This is the controller:
public function getDeliveryItems($deliveryId)
    {
        $delivery = InventoryTransaction::find($deliveryId);
        $deliveryItems = InventoryMovement::where('inventory_transaction_id', $deliveryId)
            ->join('inventory', 'inventory_movement.inventory_id', '=', 'inventory.id')
            ->select([
                'inventory.id',
                'inventory.medicine_name',
                'inventory.brand',
                'inventory.expiry_date',
                'inventory_movement.quantity',
                'inventory.purchase_price as unit_price',
                'inventory_movement.quantity',
            ])
            ->get();

        $data = [
            'transaction_date' => $delivery->transaction_date,
            'doc_no' => $delivery->doc_no,
            'name' => $delivery->name,
            'items' => $deliveryItems,
        ];

        return response()->json($data);        
    }

And this is the script:
<script>
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#delivery-list').on('click', 'tr', function() {
        var deliveryId = $(this).data('id');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/get-delivery-items/' + deliveryId,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                //populate call
                populateFormAndTable(data);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.error('AJAX request failed:', status, error);
                console.log('Response:', xhr.responseText);
                alert('An error occurred while fetching delivery items. Please try again.');
            }
        });
    });

    function populateFormAndTable(data) {
        // Populating the form fields
        $('#date').val(data.transaction_date);
        $('#docs_no').val(data.doc_no);
        $('#supplier').val(data.name);

        // Populating the table with items
        var itemsHtml = '';
        $.each(data.items, function(index, item) {
            itemsHtml += '<tr>';
            itemsHtml += '<td>' + item.id + '</td>';
            itemsHtml += '<td>' + item.medicine_name + '</td>';
            itemsHtml += '<td>' + item.brand + '</td>';
            itemsHtml += '<td>' + item.expiry_date + '</td>';
            itemsHtml += '<td>' + item.quantity + '</td>';
            itemsHtml += '<td>' + item.unit_price + '</td>';
            itemsHtml += '<td>' + (item.quantity * item.unit_price) + '</td>'; 
            itemsHtml += '</tr>';
        });       

        //showing the delivery tab and closing the modal
        $('#myTab a[href="#delivery"]').tab('show');
        $('#deliveryDetailsModal').modal('hide');
        $('#delivery-items').html(itemsHtml);
    }
});

</script>

I tried to pass the data into a view but I'm having problems regarding some unidentified variables. I'm including the delivery, itemlist, and withdrawals in a page that's why I am passing a some data into a same view (which might cause error? not sure guys)

Don't know where there's supposed to be a "redirect" here. It looks like your browser simply shows the JSON response your endpoint gave - which means, your form submitted the normal way. Could be due to some JS error preventing it from actually performing the AJAX request; or because your click handler never triggers to begin with, or because you might have neglected to cancel some default action. Since you neglect to show us the actual form, can't say for sure.
